# Exit the recursion without method returning anything

Tags: java, recursion

I don't know if the title is formed correctly but this is what i ask

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
    sum(a, 0, 0);
}

private static void sum(int[] arr, int index, int sum) {
    if (index == arr.length) {
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    for (int i = index; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum(arr, index + 1, sum + arr[index]);
    }
}
```

I just wan't to print the answer, but it's printing it a lot of times then ofc i get stackOverflow exception

Comment: add `return;` after `System.out.println(sum);`

Comment: ^^ or `else`, to reflect the fundamental logic.

Comment: if i add return after it i still get endless printing of of 45 on the console

Comment: Side note: Avoid using the same name for a method (`sum`) and a parameter to the method (`sum`), not least from a readability perspective.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? If it's just supposed to add up the contents of the array, why do you need a `for` loop _and_ recursion?

Comment: @ВсеЕдно: By far, the best way to understand what's going on and fix it is to use the debugger built into your IDE to step through the code statement-by-statement, look at your variables and parameters, etc., etc. Using a debugger is not an advanced skill; it's a fundamental tool it's important to learn to use early.

Comment: It prints lots of times because you don't just make one recursion, you make 10! (10 factorial). You don't have to use that `for` because you only need to enter once every recursion.

Comment: "What is this code supposed to do" practising recursion, just want to print the sum of the numbers that's all

Comment: after adding `return` it should not be **endless** printing, just **very** often: 10! = 3,628,800 times

Comment: He thinks it's endless because it crashes before the end of it. And with good cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer what I think your question means, **all recursive functions must return.** Otherwise they will never leave the function.

I'm going to assume the eventual result you want is a recursive code for adding numbers. Here's all the issues with your code.

1. Firstly, **don't use the for-loop in your function**. Recursion is used as a **substitute** for loops. Using both is like putting a for-loop within a for-loop that's attempting to do the same task.
2. Second, recursive functions **must have a return statement**. Without this, it will not be able to break out. I'm not going to explain the basics of recursion here, but if you'd like, [here's a guide on how recursion works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozmE8G6YKww). I'd recommend watching this or learning about the concept of recursion before trying to understand my code.
3. The best way to use a recursive function here is to return the sum to your main function, rather than print it in the recursive function itself.  In each iteration of the recursive function, you can return the value of sum + add(arr, --n, sum). For this, it will have to return an int (I accidentally omitted this until  Shinra tensei pointed it out).
4. Not mandatory, but please don't name your function(sum) the same name as an important variable. Java won't penalise you, but you won't understand your own code. I've renamed your function to "add".

With this in mind, here's a simple recursive code to add numbers in an array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
    System.out.println(add(a, 0, 0)); // Receives the final value from add
}

private static int add(int[] arr, int index, int sum) {
    if (index == arr.length) {
        // You could print 'sum' here, but may as well return it to the main function and print it there.
        return (sum);
    }   
    sum += arr[index]; 
    else {
      return sum + add(arr, --n, sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not necessarily need a return statement, since it's a void and not anything else. But it would be definitely better as an int function.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove for loop then it will work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
    sum(a, 0, 0);
}

private static void sum(int[] arr, int index, int sum) {
if (index == arr.length)
    System.out.println(sum);
else
    sum(arr, index + 1, sum + arr[index]);
```

}

Comment: This will throw an exception

Comment: Yep else statement was missing @Shinratensei

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
        System.out.println(sum(a, 0, 0));
    }


    private static int sum( int[] arr, int index, int result ) 
    {
        result += arr[index ];  
        if ( index + 1 <arr.length) {  
        return sum( arr, index + 1, result);
        }
        else {
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It have following errors:

- *Logical Error* : Because you are using `loop` and `recursion` both.
- `for-loop` is calling `private static void sum(int[] arr, int index, int sum)` method recursively and causing `stake` problem.

You can use following code(see [here](http://ideone.com/XknHUf) working):

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
        System.out.println("In main sum is: " + sum(a, 0, 0));
    }

    private static int sum(int[] arr, int index, int sum) {
        if (index == arr.length) {
            return sum;
        }

        return sum(arr, index + 1, sum + arr[index]);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Even though your code will produce desirable result but, it will consume a lots of `stack-memory`. When I run it at my local machine then it is calling `private static int sum(int[] arr, int index, int sum)` method `9864100` times!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, first of all you need to understand well what is the difference between iteration and recursion. I'm not an expert so I can't give you a proper explanation, but to sum it up, iteration is made using `while` and `for` loops, while recursion is made calling the function you're already in, changing one of the parameters. As I said, not a very good explanation, I recommend using google.

So, what you're doing is both at the same time. You're using recursion like this:

```
private static void sum(int[] arr, int index, int sum) {
...
    sum(arr, index + 1, sum + arr[index]);
}
```

while iterating like this:

```
for (int i = index; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum(arr, index + 1, sum + arr[index]);
}
```

It can make sense in other situations, but not in this one, because both are used to do the same, which is simply add the numbers of the same array. What you should have done is this:

```
private static void sum(int[] arr, int index, int sum) {
    if (index == arr.length) {
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
    else{
        sum(arr, index + 1, sum + arr[index]);
    }
}
```

This way, when `index == arr.length` you print the result, and the execution exits all the `sum` functions. If you keep the `for` loop there, it will exit the function once, but it will enter again until the loop has been completed, that is, until `i == arr.length`, which is loooooooots of times.

There is another way to do it which uses an `int` function instead of a `void` method. Try to find the way to do that too, it's a good way to practise recursion.